# How to use for loop to split fasta in two columns in R without using any packages?

Tags: r, for-loop, sequence, fasta

I have a fasta file which looks like the following, with other headers and corresponding sequence. How do I write a code with a "for loop" that  converts it to a data frame where the ORF name is stored in column 1 and the corresponding upstream and downstream sequence is stored in column 2? (Using R studio)

```
>YAL001C TFC3 SGDID:S000000001, Chr I from 152168-146596, reverse complement, Verified ORF, "Largest of six subunits of the RNA polymerase III transcription initiation factor complex (TFIIIC); part of the TauB domain of TFIIIC that binds DNA at the BoxB promoter sites of tRNA and similar genes; cooperates with Tfc6p in DNA binding"
ACTTGTAAATATATCTTTTATTTTCCGAGAGGAAAAAGTTTCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AGAAGAAAAATAACTTTCTCATGTAATAAAAGGTAACTAATGTAGACAAAAAAGTATACA
TTTAGCTTTTCTTTTTTTGATGATTTTTGAGTTTCATGTTACTAATCAGAACAATTAACG
```

Comment: the fasta is missing a ">" right? You can use readDNAStringSets from Biostrings

Comment: it has the ">" at the beginning.  I did put it but its not showing when I post it. I have to do this without a package.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a try.

```
tmp <- scan("foo.fa",sep="\n",what="character")
tmp.paste <- paste(tmp,collapse="\t")
tmp.fa <- strsplit(tmp.paste,">")[[1]]
tmp.dt <- t(sapply(tmp.fa,function(x){
  x1 <- strsplit(x,"\t")[[1]]
  x1.head <- strsplit(x1[1]," ")[[1]][1]
  x1.fa <- paste(x1[-1],collapse="")
  x1.fa <- gsub("\t","",x1.fa)
  c(x1.head,x1.fa)
}))
colnames(tmp.dt) <- c("ORFID","Fasta")
```

Answer (score 0):

I rely on stringr for string manipulation so I used that, I'm not sure if you meant no packages as in no fasta modifying packages but here is a for loop as requested.

```
library(stringr)

#read in fasta
fa <- readLines("./test.fa")

#initialize empty data frame
df <- data.frame()

for (line in fa) {
  if (startsWith(line, ">")) {
    lin <- str_extract(line, "(\".+)(\")")
    df[nrow(df)+1,c(1,2)] <- c(substr(lin, 2, nchar(lin)-1), str_extract(line, "[0-9]+-[0-9]+"))
  }
}
#change col names
colnames(df) <- c("ORF", "SEQloc")
```

If you are only interested in the header lines of the fasta, could perform some upfront edits to the file before loading it in R with:

```
grep "^>" test.fa > header_only_test.fa
```